# How to align text in line with icons?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/acz3hhsL/

Code:HTML

```
     <div id="contact-info">
                      <div id="adresa">
                     <div id="addPadding" style="padding: 2em;">
                     <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/ADRESA.png"                      style="width:22px;height:31px;float:left;display: inline;">
                   <div style="float: right;display: inline;width: 80%;">
  <p style="text-align:left;font-size:14px;color:black;">Calea Dorobantilor,nr.74,<br>bl.Y9,SC.2,Ap.25<br>Cluj-Napoca,400609<br>Romania</p>


                      </div>

                     </div>
                     </div>



                     <div id="telefon">
                     <div id="addPadding" style="padding: 60px 2em;">
                     <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/TELEFON.png"                      style="width:22px;height:31px;float:left;display: inline;">
                   <div style="float: right;display: inline;width: 80%;">
  <p style="font-size:14px;color:black;text-align:left;">Tel./Fax (004) 0264 448 579<br>Tel.(004) 0744 490 776</p>


                      </div>

                     </div>
                     </div>      

                   <div id="mail">
                     <div id="addPadding" style="padding: 20px 2em;">
                     <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/E-MAIL.png"                      style="width:26px;height:19px;float:left;display: inline;">
                   <div style="float: right;display: inline;width: 80%;">
  <p style="font-size:14px;color:black;text-align:left;">office@codoban.com</p>


                      </div>

                     </div>
                     </div>       
                        </div>

                  </div>
```

Code CSS:

```
 #contact-info
{
width:268px;
height:270px;
background:url(http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/BODY-CONTACT.png);
position:absolute;
right:0;
}
```

This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

I changed the text font size and unfortunately not displayed inline with icon sites.

How can I get him back but `font-size:14px;`

Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
p {margin: 0;}
```

to your CSS, that removes the gaps/offset of the text. http://jsfiddle.net/acz3hhsL/2/